# proving that concave function is bigger than specific functions

Tags: functions

**Note: as requested I published a new question:**

given $():[0,2];[0,∞)$ which is a concave function, in other words for every $,$ in $[0,2]$ the following is true for every $λ$ in $[0,1]$:

$(λ+(1−λ))≥λ()+(1−λ)()$

Given the above formula and that $f(1)=1$, I need to prove:

1. $()≥$ in $[0,1]$
2. $f(x)≥2-x$ in $[1,2]$

In my previous post you helped me prove **a**, and here is the answer which I got:

> $()=(⋅1+(1−)⋅0)≥(1)+(1−)(0)=+(1−)(0).$
>
> Then note that $(1−)≥0$ and $(0)≥0$, hence $(1−)(0)≥0$.
>
> Thus, $()≥+(1−)(0)≥+0=$

But how can I prove b? it seems that the same technique doesn't work in this condition.

Comment: Just reflect the diagram about the line $x=1$. It's exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in [1,2]$ and call $\lambda=x-1$. Then
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=f(1+\lambda)=f(\lambda.2+ (1-\lambda)1)\geq \lambda f(2)+(1-\lambda)f(1)=\\
&=\lambda f(2)+(1-\lambda)\geq 1-\lambda=2-x
\end{align*}